# How to prevent seconds exceed 60 using momentjs?

Tags: javascript, mysql, momentjs

I am using momentjs CDN but sometimes seconds are more than 60 getting error when i want to save it in DB.

```
  const currentDate = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS");
  const onlyDate = moment(currentDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");

  formData.append("comment", comments.value);
  formData.append("fecha", currentDate);

  formData.append("idTesis", idTesisParam);
  formData.append("user", userId);
  formData.append("onlyDate", onlyDate);
  formData.append("estado", statusTesis);
  formData.append("aprobado", aprobado);
```

Error:

```
Failed: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2022-10-07 09:10:69' for column 'fecha'
```

I am sending formData (`fecha` is storing `currentDate`), then in backend i am inserting in DB column `fecha` (mysql datetime type)

Comment: `SS` maps to fractional seconds, need to use `ss`, and you likely want to use `mm` for the minutes.

Comment: https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/01-format/

Answer (score 0):

SS - Fractional Second

ss - Second

It matters if the "ss" is big or small - see: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

do

```
const currentDate = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```